# woocommerce get_price_html not pulling in correct price

Tags: loop, woocommerce-offtopic, query

I have created a custom loop to pull in a few select products.

I was originally getting the price like this:

```
$get_price = get_post_meta( $pid, '_regular_price', true);
```

Obviously this then doesnt apply any filters added to the 'woocommerce_get_price_html' hook.

The price stored for this specific product is: £8.73

I then attempted to get the price like this:

```
$_product = wc_get_product( $pid );
$pricenew = $_product->get_price();
```

Which returns a completely different price (£10.21) to what is show on the single product page.

I also tried the following:

```
$_product = wc_get_product( $pid );
$pricenew = $_product->get_price_html();
```

Again this returns another completely different price of £6.79.

Any suggestions on what could be going on? I can confirm i am fetching the correct prices for the corresponding product ids.

My question is, how can i get the correct price after any filters have been applied to the price.

Comment: Do you have taxes set up? Depending on your settings/location `get_price_html()` will return the price with/without tax.

Comment: no taxes are setup currently